# Jenkins (groovy) get list from shell script

Tags: shell, jenkins, groovy, jenkins-groovy

Can I pass list of elements from WORKSPACE to Groovy script?

What I mean, I have some File in Jenkins workspace with elements

```
"element1", "element2", "element3", "element4"
```

I want to pass this file like a list to Groovy script

```
List components = ["element1", "element2", "element3", "element4"]
```

I tried to use

```
List componentsList = []

env.Components = sh(script: "cat $WORKSPACE/File", returnStdout: true).trim().componentsList.addAll()
```

But it doesn't work (error message from Jenkins)

```
groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such field found: field java.lang.String componentsList
```

P.S. I need this list for create a Map from 2 lists in the future

Btw, I think I can avoid using `sh` for getting content from file. Probably better to use Groovy instruments for that?

P.S.S.

After applied variant from @chubbsondubs

```
def componentsFile = "WORKSPACE/Components" 
def linksFile = "WORKSPACE/Links"

def components = new File(componentsFile).collect { it.trim() } 
def links = new File(linksFile).collect { it.trim() } 

def result = [components, links].transpose().collect { component, link -> 
  [name: component, link: link]
}

println result
```

I got

```
[[name:component1, component2, component3, component4, link: link1, link2, link3, link4]]
```

But I need to get

```
[[name:component1, link:link1], [name:component2, link:link2], [name:component3, link:link3], [name:component4, link:link4]]
```

Could you please help me to get the result above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd skip trying to use `sh()` since all it's doing is reading the file.  I'd do something like this to read the file:

```
env.Components = readFile("File").trim().split(",") as List
```

You can skip defining the List and skip sh altogether.  Using `readFile` will read a file into a String from the current working directory which is most likely the workspace root.

Remember you need to wrap your code in a `script {}` for the `readFile` to work.

An alternative, if `readFile` isn't working is the following:

```
env.Components = new File("File").text.trim().split(",") as List
```

One thing to consider is **if those components were on separate lines** you could do this and skip the split (if you control the format of this file):

```
env.Components = new File("File").collect { it.trim() }
```

To get the map you'll need to the following:

```
(0..<components.size()).collectEntries { i -> [ components[i], links[i] ] }
```

But components.size() == links.size() and if it doesn't it'll fail. That's an exercise left for the reader though.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I got some error `Caught: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: links.readFile() is applicable for argument types: (String) values: [WORKSPACE/File]` from the first variant of your answer. I need to get List for use it in Map next

Comment: A couple of things to note.  The 2nd suggestion was IF you had your elements 1 per line then you didn't need to do a `split`.   I'm going to update the answer a bit to discuss this more as it's kind of long.